# Why is my JSON-Data not deserialized correctly with Unitys JsonUtility?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I want to access the real-time position of the ISS, but deserializing with `JsonUtility.FromJson` gives me null values.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
   Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else {
   string jsonString = www.downloadHandler.text;
   Debug.Log(jsonString);
   ISS issData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ISS>(jsonString);
   Debug.Log(issData.name);
}
```

This is my ISS Class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ISS
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double altitude { get; set; }
    public double velocity { get; set; }
    public string visibility { get; set; }
    public double footprint { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public double daynum { get; set; }
    public double solar_lat { get; set; }
    public double solar_lon { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}
```

Debug.Log gives me the following:

```
{"name":"iss","id":25544,"latitude":-51.26475894394,"longitude":70.742077900276,"altitude":430.55414597218,"velocity":27557.250778742,"visibility":"daylight","footprint":4560.7731250695,"timestamp":1572781486,"daynum":2458790.9894213,"solar_lat":-15.053235454665,"solar_lon":359.70413044191,"units":"kilometers"}

Null
```

Although instead of "Null" it should give me the name "iss". I'm curious why this isn't working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please convert a class object to JSON and reverse from the same to identify issue. I have given a solution for web. Please try this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. I still get "Null" in Debug.Log

Answer (score 0):

I ended up importing JsonDotNet from the AssetStore. In my script I added:

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

and replaced

`JsonUtility.FromJson<ISS>(jsonString)`

with the Deserialize Function from JsonDotNet:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ISS>(jsonString);`

This made it work.